# Pass Value of Mat Select from Component file to Service File in Angular

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I have an API which requires country code in header along with authorization token and Bearer. I am able to fetch mat-select value in my component file. However my api header and token are being set in service file. Can anyone help me figure out how do I pass the value of mat-select from component to service file?

For now I am hard coding the country Value as 'au' but I want it to set it as per mat-select dropdown value.

Code to fetch mat-select value in Component File:

```
onCountrySelection() {
console.log(this.countryValue);
}
```

API in service Class File:

```
uploadConfig(templateName, JsonBody) {
const header = new HttpHeaders().set(
'Authorization',
'Bearer ' + sessionStorage.getItem('token'),
).set(
'country',
'au'
);
return this.httpClient.post(
this.localUrl + '/pattern/' + templateName + '/flow', JsonBody,
{ headers: header }); 
}
```

How can I get the value from console.log of Component to Service file

Comment: On dropdown change you can save the value to a service and then retrieve the same when you need.

Answer (score 0):

Try like this

```
uploadConfig(templateName, JsonBody) {
    const header = new HttpHeaders({
        'Authorization':  'Bearer ' + sessionStorage.getItem('token'),
        'country': sessionStorage.getItem('countryCode')
    })
    return this.httpClient.post(this.localUrl + '/pattern/' + templateName + '/flow', JsonBody,{ headers: header }).subscribe(); 

}
```

Comment: If I use like this then for some reason I am not able to hit API. I am not able to see the hit in network(After pressing F12).

Comment: here is demo please check https://angular-rt8dvz.stackblitz.io/